# When to take your cat to an emergency vet?

Tags: cats, veterinarian

I was wondering what symptoms in a cat indicate it should be immediately seen by an emergency vet?

I know obviously if the cat has an injury, or is in obvious distress, but are there any less obvious ones? Like, for instance, I know head pressing is a sign of a serious neurological problem. Does that kind of thing warrant an emergency vet visit?

I was hoping for a decent list, so I have some idea in advance of an emergency when exactly it's time to go to the emergency vet versus just you can wait until the regular vet the next day.

Comment: Also keep in mind that some things may wait until the next day okay, but not over a weekend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by no means an exhaustive list, but things you would not want to wait to take your cat in for:

- seizures
- collapse or paralysis
- inappropriate mentation or unconsciousness
- suspected pain
- severe bleeding
- injury or trauma
- suspected toxin ingestion
- suspected foreign body or string ingestion
- suspected allergic reaction
- repeated or acute vomiting
- male cat straining to urinate
- difficulty breathing or choking

The bottom line is that if you are concerned enough to be asking should we go to the vet now, you probably should go to the vet now. If in doubt, take your cat in – better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: to add to this answer,if a cat do stop eating or drinking for more than a day you need to get it to the vet.if your cat goes into hiding from you and try to avoid normal interaction it might be in pain and you shuld take it to the vet.