# How concerned should I be that my cat only goes to the toilet with long breaks and at my wife's urging?

Tags: cats, urination

My cat is an old indoor Norwegian Forest Cat (6 years) and a bit human dependant like needing his water held. 
Last time he excreted and urinated after about 3 days without urinating and only tried and succeeded after urging of my wife. He excreted previously after 2 days with urging. Urging is putting him in the toilet and discouraging him from leaving. He was rarely before this poor at toilet going. Some days very regular and some days 2 days break in excretion.
Nothing major has changed except we are getting Summer heat.

Going to the vet is stressful for him so we don't take going lightly. Being at the vet is no problem.     Should we worried enough to get him checked?

Update: He went to toilet tonight by himself- about a day since last time.

Comment: There is already an answer that tells you to take your cat to the vet, which I support. But here are some questions that could be relevant at your vet or here if you wish to continue to discuss this topic depending on what the vet said:
What do you feed your cat? How much does your cat drink? Did you ever notice that your cat eats something that is not edible (e.g. strings, plastic, ...)? How much does your cat move during a typical day? Did you notice anything about the excreta of your cat? E.g. very dark color, so dry no cat litter sticks to it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if a cat changes behaviour you need to take it to the vet.

By changes I mean altered toileting. It is normal for most cats to use the litter box to pee two times a day and to defecate once a day, but many cats are poor drinkers so if they only pee once a day it is ok and not a reason to worry.

If a cat stops eating and drinking for more than a day, you need to take it to the vet. If a cat does not eat for more than 24 hours their liver might be at risk of damage and this can be very serious.

Other types of change are if your cat goes into hiding and avoids being handled. This can be a sign your cat is in pain. I am not saying you need to worry if your cat wants some alone time but you know your cat and are the one who will know if something is unusual.

A little about when you need to take the cat to the emergency vet: [When to take your cat to an emergency vet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20656/when-to-take-your-cat-to-an-emergency-vet)

Comment: As in the question you linked, this is a male cat having difficulty urinating, and therefore it should be brought to the emergency vet to make absolutely sure nothing is wrong ASAP. Male cats are prone to UTIs, which can end up life threatening if it goes really badly.

Comment: More than life threatening UTIs, older male cats can have their urethra blocked entirely, which is fatal if not treated quickly. The implication that he does not drink much water puts him at even more risk of crystals and blocking.